# Should we allow the "definition and application" questions?

Tags: discussion

I have asked a questions about the definition of [average speed and its application](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/meaning-and-application-of-average-speed-closed) on this site, but it get closed. It should be acceptable, because physical quantities are the basic of mathematical analysis. Without it you can do nothing meaningful. So it is natural to seek their application.

How about if someone come up some special definition and want to know the application?

- How about if someone someday come up with the idea of spin-correlation and ask whether it may can show the phase transition of some models?
- How about if they ask where can they apply the vortex-correlation?
- Is the size of spin cluster has applications?
- Is the average of loop length has any correlation to the magnetization, superconductivity, etc?

Why we cannot ask such kind of questions in this forum? This fit well here as physics questions, so we may seek the others opinions on the subject and someone might help each other.

My question is clear and the definition is unambiguously, don't you think that it should be allowed?

Comment: hwlau, I don't think this is a problem of question asking for definition or not. As I see it, your question has two completely different problems. 1) it's not quite clear what you are asking for, 2) it's way too basic. I mean, spin-correlation is fine. That isn't something you hear normal people talking about. But average speed? I mean come on... 6 year old kid can explain that to you (okay, maybe not 6 but 10). So unless you'll convince us that there is something hugely non-trivial in your question, it should remain closed.

Comment: @Marek: I have updated it

Answer (score 3):

When I read the title, I thought "hey, I can get on board with that!" But then I read the question that started this meta thread, and I have to agree with Marek. Applications of average velocity do not seem at all appropriate for this site.

So I will answer the question in your title:
I think these kinds of questions are important and helpful if the level is appropriate. They have definite answers and are certainly informative. We keep on coming back to what is "appropriate."

I don't know if i have much more to say about it...